# Pass <br/> as part of a custom component's attribute value - compile error

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, stylesheets

Hi I tried to provide line break for the text however Iam facing this issue.

```
                    </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                    
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!order.Type=='Mobile Clock'}">
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <table style="width:50%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:right;width:35%;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;color:#4a4a56;padding-right: 2px;">
                                <c:helpicon helpText="NOT REQUIRED:The Employee can punch in and out anywhere and the app does not track where the punch took place.<br/>
                                                      GEO-LOCATION REQUIRED:Allows punches from anywhere.Requires location services to be enabled on the employees cell phone.The app will record where the punch took place.<br/>
                                                      GEO-FENCE WARNING:A geo fence is set around a location.IF any employee punches outside this location a warning will appear.The employee has the option to continue to punch in or they can choose not to punch in.<br/>
                                                      GEO-FENCE REQUIRED:Employee is required to be within the geo fence location in order to punch into or out using the application."/>
                              Clock Location Restrictions
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                <apex:outputLabel value="." styleClass="required"></apex:outputLabel>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!order.Clock_Location_Restriction__c}">
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="clockinformation" oncomplete="this.focus();" status="ocstatus"/>
                                </apex:inputField>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Error Message: Missing required attribute helpText in  in OONewClientOAFS2 at line 167 column 37

Code that i have used 
 but did not faced any error.

```
     </tr>
                </table>      
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:actionRegion >                    
                <table >
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:right;width:100px!important;font-weight:bold;font-size:11px;color: #4a4a56;padding-right: 2px;">
                            <c:helpicon helpText="Virtual Clock is a webpage where employees can go to in order clock in and out from.<br/>   
                                                  Phone Clock is a phone number in which employees call to clock in and out.<br/>  
                                            Web Timesheet is a web based login, where employees manually enter their worked hours."/>
                            Order Type 
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                            <apex:outputLabel value="." styleClass="required"></apex:outputLabel>
                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedOrderType}" size="1" id="OrderType" title="Please select the type of Order" label="Please select the type of Order">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!orderTypes}"/>
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="ordercontactinfo" action="{!fillOrderType}" status="ocstatus"/>                                     
                            </apex:selectList>
```

Comment: Most likely because you have literal newlines in your attribute value. Try combining them into one line.

Comment: @sfdcfox I tried making it one line as well still throws me same error.

Comment: @sfdcfox I tried the same method in different Page i did not got any error there.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I finally recognised the error.

It was my mistake accidentally i have choose the API version in the Dev Console as 15 which was the reason for this.

I dont get this error any more.

Thanks For your help @sfdcfox.